# Changing text on lockscreen

Tags: android, xml, layout

How to change the lockscreen text ?

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me

Comment: Is it default android lock or any market app?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by the developer of the custom rom that you are using. There isn't an easy way unless you want to change the rom itself.

Another option is to use a third party lockscreen, that you can download from Android Market, but that would change the entire lockscreen not just the text.

[This is one of the most popular lockscreen apps.](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qaXViYW5nLmdvc2NyZWVubG9jayJd)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit System Apps. 
I would suggest you to go for Lock Applications in Android Market. They can't remove the system App. But it will replace the System App as default App.